# wxWidgets application loop slideshow

Tags: multithreading, loops, slideshow, wxwidgets

I have a rather simple problem which I can't seem to solve.

I would like to write a slideshow program that also plays an audio file everytime the slide has changed. This audio files vary in lengths and I do not want to program to loop through the next entry / picture till the sound has finished playing.

Currently I have implemented a loop:

```
void UI_BRAINWASH::PlaySound_top()
{
wxString tmppath(parent->get_currentdirect()+parent->current_db.get_card(m_index)->get_topentryaudiopath());
ISound* firstsound = this->engine->play2D(tmppath.mb_str(), false, false, true); 
while(engine->isCurrentlyPlaying(tmppath.mb_str()))
{
    StaticTextTop->GetParent()->Update();
    //wxSleep(3);

}
m_timer->Start(1000);
```

}

and this loops through the entries as expected and everything is dandy...

However, I would like, to be able to abort the programm by pressing the Escape amongst other things, but the while loop obviously hinders me from doing exactly that.
I also noticed that I can't move my window or close the programm while it is looping through the pictures.

So I have looked at threads and the wxIdleevent class. in: wxwidgets/samples/threads/ is an example of a "workers thread", which seems to be what I need.

My question now is: are threads not a bit of an overkill for a simple slideshow?
Is there another / better way of looping through my entries - waiting for the sound to have played, updating the gui and also being able to still move the window around?

Answer (score 0):

What is engine?

Most APIs for playing sounds provide the ability to start playing a sound-file and then return immediatly.  They will send an event when the sound is finished.  They will also provide a call to interrupt a sound that is still playing.  This is what you want.

You should check the docs for whatever API you are using and find this feature.  If the feature is not available, than you need to find another API that does - most do.